# CSS forcing a div to follow class

Tags: html, css

So I have a div that follows a CSS script, in this script it's defined as the following:

```
#div { height: 30px; width: 30px; float:left;}
```

I need the divs properties, but for it to instead float to the right and plan to do so using a class:

```
.class {float: right}
```

However this doesn't work (it still float to the left).

Is there a way to force the div to follow the class over its own predetermined properties?

Comment: you could use an " !important " , to be more precise , you can also enter the html used ?

Comment: Look at this article: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: ``!important`` is a bit overkill. 

In your code, it does not apply because the way CSS evaluate rules. An id has a more important score than a class. To beat the score, you should just modify as ``#div.class {float: right}``. It is important no to use too much ``!important`` because it is kind of super power when you can not reach the score easily.

Comment: Thanks Aureliano Far Suau! That solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run into CSS [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue.

An `id` selector has higher specificity compared to a `class` selector so it's values cannot be overridden using just a `class` selector.

There are two ways to override the property of the `id` selector:

1. Use `!important` suffix to force the browser to select the class attribute value. However, using `!important` has it's own [set of problems](http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/).
2. A better solution would be use [multi-selector syntax](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) to target the div you want to style.

For example,

```
<p id="foo" class="bar">
Hello
</p>
```

CSS:

```
#foo {   color: red; }
.bar {   color: green !important; } /* avoid */
#foo.bar {    color: yellow;    } /* multi selector*/
```

See my [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rgydbamq/1/) on how to use `!important` or `multi-selector`.

Comment: Please, please don't use `!important` when you have specificity options available like `#foo.bar`.